# Check is a character in a string matches with a range of indexes of a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a password generator. I have figured out how to ensure my password has a number, uppercase and lowercase character. The password is being generated randomly from the `string.printable` function.

Here is the part of `string.printable` which I am using as accepted characters in my password:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

I am trying to ensure that at least one of the character falls withing the range of indexes from `!` to `~` which will ensure I have a special character in my password. Can someone help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
import random
import string


def password_generator(length):
    while True:
        my_password = ''
        for eachItem in range(length):
            my_password += string.printable[random.randint(0, len(string.printable) - 7)]
        if (any(x.isupper() for x in my_password) and any(x.islower() for x in my_password)
                and any(x.isdigit() for x in my_password)):
            return my_password


pass_length = int(input("Enter desired length of password: "))
print(password_generator(pass_length))
```

Comment: There are easier ways to do that. Create one set of characters per "group" - draw one character from each group. Make a combined group of all characters. Draw the remaining characters from that. Mix all what youve drawn to gether - done.

Comment: But that means the index positions for those single characters from each group will be fixed. Which takes away some of the randomness. Right?

Comment: You can call `random.shuffle` on the password's characters before returning it to randomise the order of groups.  You need to build the password as a list (which is more efficient than building a string in a loop anyway), shuffle the list and then convert to a string like `password = ''.join(list_of_password_characters)`

Comment: @ShashwatJohari - no - thats why you shuffle them again before returning them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main propose is to generate passwords that contain special characters, not to check if these passwords contain special characters, but anyway, if you want to check it, just use the following code:

```py
start = string.printable.find('!')
end = string.printable.find('~') + 1
special_chars = string.printable[start:end]
has_special_character = any(map(lambda c: c in chars, my_password))
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier:

- choose 1 random letter of each special group
- chose remaining letters of all possibible characters
- mix them up and join letters into a word

---

```
import random
import string 

def password_generator(length):

    allchar = string.printable  # that is about what your choice of characters is
    low = string.ascii_lowercase
    hig = string.ascii_uppercase
    spec = string.punctuation
    nums = string.digits

    pw = []

    # ensure that each group has at least 1 character of these groups
    pw.append(random.choice(low))
    pw.append(random.choice(hig))
    pw.append(random.choice(spec))
    pw.append(random.choice(nums)) 

    # and fill up with random from all groups
    pw.extend(random.choices(allchar, k=length-len(pw)))

    # mix the positions up
    random.shuffle(pw)
    # return as string
    return "".join(pw)

pass_length = int(input("Enter desired length of password: "))
for _ in range(10):
    print(password_generator(pass_length))
```

Output:

```
b]gDEK7:wM9_T__N:ugO
l1c2p3"rW)FB@=k]'1p~
9U=M'R3"Kbzqo/~8+Dr{
g`_w7tvL#Ulto&Q4Qi]"
O7(DttWffx4N7lr~B)h$
Azd2[HHTn:X!L\5^'\~`
%Sq}be2V<\eM^$$;)V@\
1}W{iBhV;u<D2@f5\m8P
E3vmhWxaWR'9hMeiU+1$
```